# Check a string for containing a list of substrings

Tags: c#-4.0

How can I check a specific string to see if it contains a series of substrings?
Specifically something like this:

```
public GetByValue(string testString) {

    // if testString contains these substrings I want to throw back that string was invalid
    // string cannot contain "the " or any part of the words "College" or "University"

   ...
}
```

Comment: Depends on how you see this evolving in the future. A regular expression might be a good start. Have you tried anything?

Comment: Not really sure where to start... my data access layer is using the string entered to do a search... if the string contains "the " or any part of the words "college" or "university" - example: "col" or "uni" - then there are too many rows returned, too generic. As far as growth, just those 3 words are all I care about. I'm using Linq to SQL in the DAL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided against checking for strings to limit my data return, instead limited my return to a .Take(15) and if the return count is more than 65,536, just return null

Answer (score 1):

If performance is a concern, you may want to consider using the [RegexStringValidator class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.regexstringvalidator.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can use string.Contains() method

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx

```
// This example demonstrates the String.Contains() method
using System;

class Sample 
{
public static void Main() 
{
string s1 = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
string s2 = "fox";
bool b;
b = s1.Contains(s2);
Console.WriteLine("Is the string, s2, in the string, s1?: {0}", b);
}
```

}
/*
This example produces the following results:

Is the string, s2, in the string, s1?: True
*/

Answer (score 0):

This an interesting question. As @Jon mentioned, a regular expression might be a good start because it will allow you to evaluate multiple negative matches at once (potentially). A naive loop would be much less efficient in comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You can check it as follow....

```
   class Program
{



public static bool checkstr(string str1,string str2)
{
 bool c1=str1.Contains(str2);
 return c1;
```

}

```
public static void Main()
{
string st = "I am a boy";
string st1 = "boy";

bool c1=checkstr(st,st1);
//if st1 is in st then it print true otherwise false
      System.Console.WriteLine(c1);
}
}
```