# String search using <List> of substrings

Tags: c#, regex, string

The question is pretty similar to these:

[Check a string for containing a list of substrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311631/check-a-string-for-containing-a-list-of-substrings)

[Check if a string contains a list of substrings and save the matching ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30261100/check-if-a-string-contains-a-list-of-substrings-and-save-the-matching-ones)

with one exception - not only to check but also to get starting index of a substring for future processing. It may look like IndexOf using `List` of strings:

```
private List<string> matches = new List<string> { "one", "two", "three" };

while (index < text.Length && -1 != (index = text.IndexOf(matches, index))) 
{                       
   ...
   // also I need to identify which one of substrings has been matched
   index += matches[?].Length;
   // further text processing...
}
```

In other words, I need to know if text string contains any substring (not word!) from the list, and if it does, get start and end positions for matched substring.

P.S: also, this method must be fast enough and case-insensitive.

Comment: What is your input string?

Comment: you've just answered the question yourseld by adding `Regex` to tags... just use it! The `Match` class gives you a lot of abilities.. like getting the `Index` or `Length` and stuff..

Comment: I did not succeed using regex. I was able to match my substrings, but  what's next? how to get positions? >>like getting the Index or Length and stuff.. Oh I did't know that. Will try later...

Comment: >>What is your input string? -- Take any string containing substrings listed above. for ex. "twoBrownFoxJumpedThreetimesblabla oneblabla"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a LINQ way to get the indices with matching keywords:

```
var matches = new List<string> { "one", "two", "three" };
var result = matches.Where(i => s.IndexOf(i, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1)
           .ToDictionary(m => s.IndexOf(m, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase), m => m);
```

With `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` we ensure case-insensitive comparison check.

Non-LINQ way:

```
List<string> matches = new List<string> { "one", "two", "three" };
for (int h = 0; h < matches.Count; h++)
{
    int idx = s.IndexOf(matches[h], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    if (idx > -1)
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Index: {0}, value: {1}",idx, matches[h]));
 }
```

And here is a regex way to obtain a dictionary of matches together with their indices in the input string:

```
List<string> matches = new List<string> { "one", "two", "three" };
matches = matches.Select(p => Regex.Escape(p)).ToList();
string s = "one and two and three";
var dict = Regex.Matches(s, string.Join("|", matches), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Cast<Match>()
                .ToDictionary(m => m.Index, m => m.Value);
```

Result:

[image]

You need to use `Match.Index` to obtain the index of the match inside the string, but to ensure your regex pattern is valid, `Regex.Escape` can turn out helpful (as you might have `?` or other regex special characters in the search words).

The `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` flag will ensure case-insensitive matching.

Comment: Will be it faster than using basic string methods N times?

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov: No idea, but if the regex is compiled and used as a static readonly field, it is very fast. I guess you are writing your own answer - please do. I just wanted to show how it can be done with `Regex`.

Comment: Thanks, it does the job. Is there any fast solutions without using regex?

Comment: I have added another LINQ-based solution. Please check. There is a difference though: Regex returns the actual keywords matched (in their actual case), but LINQ returns the keywords found.

Comment: Thanks for LINQ, but is there any solutions targeting .NET 2.0 ? (but it's not critical)